# Python script to get last execution results from testlink

Tags: python

I'm new to python, i need to get last execution results from teslink.
i have already reported testcase results to teslink by using API

```
result = api.reportTCResult(testcaseID, testplanID, Build, 'P', notes)
```

Now i need the results back so, please help me with how to get execution results and which API need to use for that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that type(api) == 'testlink.testlinkapigeneric.TestlinkAPIClient'

```
api.getLastExecutionResult(testplanID, testcaseID, [buildid = build_number])[0]
```

Build number is optional.

You can use this to generate Python TestLink API documentation and explore other TestLink methods/APIs.

```
for m in testlink.testlinkargs._apiMethodsArgs.keys():
    print(tls.whatArgs(m), '\n')
```